# Too few parameters in OpenRecordset code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have two sets of code, that are the same I just change variables to another set that exist and now with the ones I changed I get an error saying "Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 6."

This is the changed code:

```
  Dim rec As Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Dim X As Variant
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("UnitMoreInfoQ")
    Const msgTitle As String = "Open Explorer"
    Const cExplorerPath As String = "C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE"
    Const cExplorerSwitches As String = " /n,/e"
    cFilePath = rec("ProjFilePath")
```

It highlights this line:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("UnitMoreInfoQ")
```

This is the first code:

```
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim X As Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("ProjectMoreInfoQ")
Const msgTitle As String = "Open Explorer"
Const cExplorerPath As String = "C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE"
Const cExplorerSwitches As String = " /n,/e"
cFilePath = rec("ProjFilePath")
```

As you can see, the line has the same amount of parameters:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("ProjectMoreInfoQ")
```

This has gotten me quite confused for awhile because of this. How do I fix this error?

Comment: where does this `UnitMoreInfoQ` is defined?

Comment: It's a query, that is started when you open the form the button that this code is in is on. This query has a column named "ProjFilePath". This column has the file location such as C:\Test

Comment: Does UnitMoreInfoQ have some parameters?

Comment: According to when I right click and go to parameters, unless that is not how you find out if it has parameters... no.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get the same result as you when testing your db, and I still don't understand the difference.  However, maybe we can still get you something which works in spite of my confusion.

The query contains 6 references to form controls, such as `[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![Text71]`.  Although you're certain that form is open in Form View when you hit the *"too few parameters"* error at `db.OpenRecordset("UnitMoreInfoQ")`, Access doesn't retrieve the values and expects you to supply them.

So revise the code to supply those parameter values.

```vb
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim X As Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
'Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("UnitMoreInfoQ")
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("UnitMoreInfoQ")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
Set rec = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset) ' adjust options as needed
```

I'm leaving the remainder of this original answer below in case it may be useful for anyone else trying to work through a similar problem.  But my best guess is this code change will get you what you want, and it *should* work if that form is open in Form View.

---

Run this statement in the Immediate window. (You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to open the Immediate window.)

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "UnitMoreInfoQ"
```

When Access opens the query, it will ask you to supply a value for the first parameter it identifies.  The name of that parameter is included in the parameter input dialog.  It will ask for values for each of the parameters.

Compare those "parameter names" to your query's SQL.  Generally something is misspelled.

---

Using the copy of your db, `DoCmd.OpenQuery("UnitMoreInfoQ")` asks me for 6 parameters.

Here is what I see in the Immediate window:

```vb
? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("UnitMoreInfoQ").Parameters.Count
 6 

for each prm in CurrentDb.QueryDefs("UnitMoreInfoQ").Parameters : _
? prm.name : next
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![Text71]
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![ClientNameTxt]
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![WorkOrderNumberTxt]
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![TrakwareNumberTxt]
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![WorkOrderCompleteChkBx]
[Forms]![WorkOrderDatabaseF]![WorkOrderDueDateTxt]
```

Make sure there is a form named *WorkOrderDatabaseF* open in Form View when you run this code:

```vb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("UnitMoreInfoQ")
```

Comment: I hope you mean put it in the button's code, as I put that code in the very beginning of the button's code and added a message box after to confirm it runs past that line. It ran past it, and stopped at the same place giving the same error. The query runs fine, with Access asking for no parameters.

Comment: Something is fishy here.  Restart Access, then use Ctrl+g to open the Immediate window and try `DoCmd.OpenQuery "UnitMoreInfoQ"`  Does it then ask for parameters?

Comment: It does not ask for them.

Comment: Interesting.  Opening the query alone behaves differently than when opened from your VBA code.  Perhaps the VBA code is corrupt.  I suggest you create and test a simple procedure which attempts only the `OpenRecordset`.  And if that one still expects parameters, I would like to see of copy of your db.  ;-)

Comment: Yup, still asked for parameters even with only `OpenRecordSet`. My database is using Access2013, so if you have a copy that runs these versions of accdb files, then I can upload it to mediafire. Just confirm you can run newer files.

Comment: My newest Access is 2010.  But doesn't 2013 allow you to save in an earlier db format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure people with 2010 can run 2013 files; here is the download link https://www.mediafire.com/?uugyd2kmf59iyri . If that does not work, I can try to save in an earlier format. They should do something about older versions not being able to open newer version files... like give people free upgrades if they bought older versions of Access. Just my thoughts though :p

Comment: The main code is located in the UnitInfoF. To open that, start from WorkOrderDatabaseF then click WorkOrder19, then click the More Info button. From here click UnitDesc 1545 and click once again more info. All 4 buttons retaining to opening folders are causing the same error and have the same code; the one that works is in a separate database I made awhile back. The old database I made does the same thing; it uses a query that was made when pushing a button to open the form the button is placed on.

Comment: Clicking the more info button in WorkOrderDatabaseF makes a query, which lists all data that is presented in WorkOrderInfoF. Once you click moreinfo again it creates the UnitMoreInfoQ which once again states all the info in UnitInfoF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42045/discussion-between-d347hxd-and-hansup)

Answer (score 1):

Does the [UnitMoreInfoQ] query execute properly on its own?  If you mistype a field in access it will treat that field as a parameter.

Comment: It does indeed, I use it to supply information onto a form's text boxes (same form that has the button). So the source of the form is UnitMoreInfoQ and it runs with no problems when the form opens; all text box data is filled out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ProjectMoreInfoQ and UnitMoreInfoQ are different queries... it sounds like one takes 6 parameters and the other doesn't.  Look at the queries in Access and see if either have parameters defined.

Comment: It says it has 0 parameters when I go to Query Design mode and right click then go to parameters.

Comment: Same thing, no parameters.